# RcppEigen: there are no arguments to 'assert' that depend on a template parameter

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

In trying to run one of the [rcppeigen](/questions/tagged/rcppeigen) examples from the [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) Gallery on Windows 10 I got the following error message:

> /R/winlibrary/3.5/RcppEigen/include/unsupported/Eigen/src/MatrixFunctions/MatrixLogarithm.h:137:60:
>   error: there are no arguments to 'assert' that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of 'assert' must be available
>   [-fpermissive]    assert(degree >= minPadeDegree && degree <=
>   maxPadeDegree);

I'm not sure what this means (I am very new to the `Eigen` library). The code was taken from the `Rcpp` Gallery:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

using Eigen::Map;                       
using Eigen::MatrixXd;                  
using Eigen::VectorXd;                 
using Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
VectorXd getEigenValues(Map<MatrixXd> M) {
SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd> es(M);
return es.eigenvalues();
}
```

I used `sourceCpp()` to compile a file saved as `TestEigen.cpp`. I'd appreciate any information on what the issue may be. I looked for similar questions here but did not find a clear answer.

Please feel free to delete my post if this question is a duplicate.

Kind regards

Comment: No problems on Linux, which uses a more recent compiler. Does it help to add `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` to the source file?

Comment: Does it help adding extra parentheses around the condition?

Comment: I suspect it may be getting mixed about with a C-level assert from R so mayb try adding `#define STRICT_R_HEADERS` before the include for RcppEigen.

Comment: I tried both, first adding `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` to the source file and adding `#define STRICT_R_HEADERS` before the RcppEigen and I still got the same error.